# JISON tokens using same characters

Tags: javascript, token, bison, jison

I have some troubles using JISON. I am trying to match 2 strings in square brackets splitted by a dot. The problem I encounter is that if any of the strings starts with a number or minus, it detects it as MINUS or NUMBER [which is right], but I want first to check if STRING regex matches the string the user inputs, and after that to check the NUMBER or MINUS.

```
%lex
%%

'-'                             return 'MINUS'
[0-9]+                          return 'NUMBER'
[_-]+                           return 'SYMBOL'
[a-zA-Z0-9_-\s]+                return 'STRING'
'.'                             return 'DOT'
'['                             return '['
']'                             return ']'
<<EOF>>                         return 'EOF'

/lex

%start program

%%

program
    : e EOF
        {console.log(JSON.stringify($1, null, 4)); return $1; }
    ;

e
    : NUMBER
        { $$ = {node: 'NUMBER', value: parseInt(yytext)}; }
    | STRING 
        { $$ = {node: 'STRING', value: yytext}; }
    | SYMBOL
        { $$ = {node: 'SYMBOL', value: yytext}; }
    | '[' STRING DOT STRING ']'
        { $$ = {node: 'SQUARE_BRACKETS', left: $2, right: $4}; }
    ;
```

It should match [2-20-March.Gum] (for example).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`STRING` will match any `MINUS`, `NUMBER` or `SYMBOL`, so if you insist that `STRING` be matched first, none of these will ever be matched and you might as well just remove them from the file. Jison just matches patterns in order until it finds one which matches.

Perhaps your intention is to match the contents of bracketed expressions differently; if so, you will need a different tokenising strategy (and you need to be clearer about what your requirements might be).

---

To be honest, I don't understand

```
 [_-]+                return SYMBOL;
```

Do you really intend `SYMBOL` to only match sequences containing dashes and underlines? (`-_____-_____-`)

Comment: Ohh, sorry I forgot to remove SYMBOL, it was just an example, I see that JISON matches the first pattern found, but is there any way to solve my problem?

Comment: @andy: only if you can articulate precisely under what circumstances `NUMBER' should be recognized

Comment: I will want to do something like this "[2-20-March.Gum] - 2" So that's why I have MINUS and NUMBER, I hoped I could do "SQUARE_BRACKETS MINUS NUMBER" as a pattern.

Comment: If you can treat the entire square bracket part as a single lexeme,  then it's easy (as long as square brackets don't nest); just write a regex which matches the entire sequence. If you want to tokenise differently inside square brackets, then you'll need to use start conditions.